# How to open pdf in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, web

How should I use ionic FileOpener? Or another way to show PDF file? I have updated, but get error.

> ```
> @Component({
>     selector: 'page-home',
>     templateUrl: 'home.html'
> }) 
> export class HomePage {
>     page2 = Page2;
>     ionViewDidLoad() {
>     }
>     pdfUrl : string;
>     pins = PINS;
>     str : string; 
>     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fileOpener: FileOpener) { 
>     }
>     onSelect(pin: Pin): void {
>         this.fileOpener.open('assets/helloworld.pdf', 'application/pdf')
>         .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
>         .catch(e => console.log('Error openening file', e));
>     }
> };
> ```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggcdg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open existing PDF file, you can use [File Opener](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/) plugin. 
First install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-opener
```

Then add this plugin to your app's module (app.module.ts):

```
...

import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    FileOpener
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you can use your plugin:

```
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';
    
    constructor(private fileOpener: FileOpener) { }
    
    ...
    
    this.fileOpener.open('path/to/file.pdf', 'application/pdf')
      .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
      .catch(e => console.log('Error openening file', e));
```

Hope I help!

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work, what can be false? I have updated question.

Comment: You need to add the plugin to your app's module. See the update answer.

Comment: `Native: tried calling FileOpener.open, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
cordovaWarn @ util.js:60
Error openening file cordova_not_available`

Answer (score 2):

Below error comes in browser only.

```
   Native: tried calling FileOpener.open, but Cordova is not available. Make 
   sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator cordovaWarn @ 
   util.js:60 Error openening file cordova_not_available.
```

you can make ionic app apk and install in device then check it is work.